# Formating data pulled from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I currently have a script that pulls a parameter from the url and displays on the page.  My problem is that I need to format the decimal place for the value.

UPDATED (This is working now. Thank you all.)

Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var url = $.url('https://www.google.com/blah/blahblah/index.htm?x=50.5200');

var x = url.param('x');

var x2 = parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);

 $("#value").text(x2);

});
```

Comment: Clarification: do you simply want it to go no further than two places after the decimal, or do you want to remove all trailing 0's?

Comment: no more than 2 decimal places.  thanks

Comment: No real reason to do this, since those places have no effect and if you put the float onto the DOM it will remove the extra 0's.

Comment: If the number is stored as an actual number, then the DOM will remove the extra 0's, otherwise if it's a string you have to do a bit of magic to remove them. However even if the value came back as a number, you'd still need to use `.toFixed(2)` in order to restrict it to two places after the decimal.

Comment: it's a string and I tried .toFixed(2) (thinking that would help) but it broke the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var decimal = '50.5230';
var num = parseFloat(decimal).toFixed(2);
console.log(num);
```

Comment: i'm pulling the data from the url then changing it

Comment: what plugin do you use? maybe the plugin is know, it's a float, and parse it.

Comment: thank you.  after playing around, i got it to work with parseFloat